# how to add a fragment multiple times inside a parent layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, animation, android-fragments

I want to add a particular layout till 14 views. So that layout can be add till 14 times not after that. I have a next destination layout after clicking on the next destination this layout should get added.

So for that I have choose fragment. Now I can add the fragment onClick of the next destination layout. But nothing happens when I again click on next destination layout. How can I add this till 14 times??

And I have a remove destination layout. OnClick of this the layout should swipe to right and should get removed by animation. How can I achieve this??

I want to do like this : [image]

GoBoxActivity

```
    nextDestination.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                //addedDestination.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //removeDestination.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                fragment = new NextDestinationFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();


        }
    });
```

Fragment layout

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.00"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/LinearAddedDestination">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="DESTINATION"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_gravity="center|right"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_clear_black_18dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="05dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="REMOVE"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="08dp"
        android:background="@drawable/line2"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_place_black_48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:text="@string/Loc"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:cursorVisible="false"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Street/Building/Place"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_description_black_48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/LocationDetails"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
        android:hint="@string/HouseDetails" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_person_black_48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="05dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:text="@string/additionalContact"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_expand_more_black_24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="08dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="05dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Phone"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/or"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">


            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/phone2"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="30dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/addFromContacts"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
        android:hint="@string/contact1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_description_black_48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:hint="Instruction"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone help please..?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a FragmentAdapter in order to manage multiple fragments. Then you have to inflate those fragments in some sort of ListView or ViewPager. Have a look at [this](https://www.airpair.com/android/list-fragment-android-studio) or [that](https://guides.codepath.com/android/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter) tutorial.

Using an OnTouchListener you are able to implement the swipe gestures to remove your fragments from List/Pager.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should use `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment)` to add new `Fragment` and use `remove()` to remove it.

For animation,you can use `fragmentManager.beginTransaction(). setTransition()` to set the animation that Android offers when fragment is added,removed.If you want to implement custom animation,you can use `fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(enterAnimation,exitAnimation)`,and write the two animation in your `XML` file.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Its getting added only once by fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment); @SamMao